# Fat Free Framework: Can I setup a model to compute a field value before save?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework, database-abstraction

Is there a way for the model to compute a field before save?

I have a schema something like this:

```
item_id
item_qty
item_price
linetotal
```

I'm trying to avoid this kind of code in my controller:

```
$model->linetotal = $f3->get('POST.item_qty') * $f3->get('POST.item_price');
$model->save();
```

Instead, I want to setup my model to compute the `linetotal` before save.

Perhaps something like the `beforeSave` callback in cakephp, or even better maybe I missed that I can set it up just like a Mapper virtual field on f3, except its a real field...

Comment: beforeSave is for the CakePHP framework, I am asking specifically about Fat Free Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for has just been released in 3.2.2. DB mappers now come with the following hooks: `beforeinsert`, `afterinsert`, `beforeupdate`, `afterupdate`, `beforeerase`, `aftererase` and `onload`.

So you could implement the `linetotal` calculation like this:

```
class myModel extends \DB\SQL\Mapper {

  static function _beforeupdate($self,$pkeys) {
    $self->linetotal = $self->item_qty * $self->item_price;
  }

  function __construct() {
    $f3=\Base::instance();
    parent::construct($f3->get('DB'),'mytable');
    $this->beforeupdate(array(__CLASS__,'_beforeupdate'));
  }

}
```

But since the calculation is also relevant for INSERT statements, you'll also need to hook the `beforeinsert` event. You could use the same function to hook both events :

```
class myModel extends \DB\SQL\Mapper {

  static function _linetotal($self,$pkeys) {
    $self->linetotal = $self->item_qty * $self->item_price;
  }

  function __construct() {
    $f3=\Base::instance();
    parent::construct($f3->get('DB'),'mytable');
    $this->beforeinsert(array(__CLASS__,'_linetotal'));
    $this->beforeupdate(array(__CLASS__,'_linetotal'));
  }

}
```

NB: an alternative way to implement the `linetotal` calculation would be to simply override the mapper `set()` method:

```
class myModel extends \DB\SQL\Mapper {

  function set($key,$val) {
    parent::set($key,$val);
    if ($key=='item_qty' || $key=='item_price')
      $this->linetotal = $this->item_qty * $this->item_price;
  }

}
```

### EDIT:

I forgot a third alternative, which actually looks more appropriate in your case: [virtual fields](http://fatfreeframework.com/databases#virtual-fields). In this case, the calculation is left to the DB engine. E.g:

```
class myModel extends \DB\SQL\Mapper {

  function __construct(){
    $f3=\Base::instance();
    parent::construct($f3->get('DB'),'mytable');
    $this->linetotal = 'item_qty * item_price';
  }

}
```

PS: don't forget to remove the `linetotal` field from your database.

Comment: I know about the virtual fields, but I didnt know I can save them back if they are actual fields?

Comment: You can't save virtual fields nor need it: they'll be computed on every SELECT without eating up space. If you prefer anyway to save the `linetotal` calculation, use one of the 2 first methods.